# Radial Solution To One Minus Laplacian $u-\Delta u = f(x) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $u$ be a solution to  $u-\Delta u = f(x) $

Such that $x \in R^3$ and $f(x)=F(|x|)$ ,$u(x)=U(|x|)$

And $F(r)=0$ for $ r\gt R_0 $ ,
$\lim_{x\to \infty} U(x)=0$

1. Find Ode such that $u$ satisfay.
2. Solve the Ode.
3. Show $\lim_{r\to \infty} re^rU(r)$ exist and compute the limit.

attempted solution:

let guess radial solution so we get the ode
$ru(r)-(ru(r))_{rr} = rf(r)$

let $v = ru(r)$ so we get $v^{''}-v=-rf(r)$
we solve the ode and get that our solution is
$c_1e^r+c_2e^{-r}+e^r\int{-0.5re^{-r}f(r)}+e^{-r}\int{0.5re^rf(r)}$
but with our conditions we get that the solution is
$c_2e^{-r}+e^r\int{-0.5re^{-r}f(r)}+e^{-r}\int{0.5re^rf(r)}$

but it doesn't seem correct.

Comment: The Laplacian for radial functions in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ can be computed as $\Delta u = U'' + \tfrac{2}{r} U$; see, for instance, Chapter 2 of Evans PDE. So I guess you are missing a first order term in the ODE

Comment: Just notice I "missed a prime" in the above comment: $\Delta u = U'' + \tfrac{2}{r} U'$. Now hopefully what I said next will make sense.

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right! My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODE and its general solution are correct, but, for the sake of definiteness, let me rewrite the latter as
$$
v(r)=c_1e^r+c_2e^{-r}-\frac{1}{2}e^r\int_0^{r}e^{-\xi}f(\xi)\xi\,d\xi
+\frac{1}{2}e^{-r}\int_0^{r}e^{\xi}f(\xi)\xi\,d\xi. \tag{1}
$$
Since $f(r)=0$ for $r>R_0$, we can rewrite $(1)$, for $r>R_0$, as
$$
v(r)=\left(c_1-\frac{1}{2}I_{-}\right)e^r+\left(c_2+\frac{1}{2}I_{+}\right)e^{-r}\qquad(r>R_0), \tag{2}
$$
where $I_{\pm}=\int_0^{R_0}e^{\pm\xi}f(\xi)\xi\,d\xi$. The condition $\lim_{r\to\infty}u(r)=\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{1}{r}v(r)=0$ implies $c_1=\frac{1}{2}I_{-}$, so $(1)$ becomes
$$
v(r)=\frac{1}{2}e^r\int_r^{R_0}e^{-\xi}f(\xi)\xi\,d\xi
+e^{-r}\left(c_2+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{r}e^{\xi}f(\xi)\xi\,d\xi\right). \tag{3}
$$
Usually, when $f(r)$ is a well-behaved function, it is required that $v(0)=0$, so that $u(0)<\infty$. Imposing this condition on $(3)$ fixes $c_2$:
$$
c_2=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{R_0}e^{-\xi}f(\xi)\xi\,d\xi=-\frac{1}{2}I_{-}. \tag{4}
$$
We can now compute the limit in item 3 of the question:
$$
\lim_{r\to\infty}re^{r}u(r)=\lim_{r\to\infty}e^{r}v(r)=\frac{1}{2}(I_{+}-I_{-})
=\int_0^{R_0}\sinh(\xi)f(\xi)\xi\,d\xi. \tag{5}
$$